N-channel MOSFET as motor driver
I tried to make a motor driver to control the speed of a motor with ESP32, N-channel MOSFET and other elements like pullback resistors, protective diodes etc.
But whenever I connect the motors to the battery, the MOSFET heats up and the ESP32 (as in the gate terminal connected to a digital pin) seems to have no control over the speed - the motors run at full speed no matter what the pin setting is.


As-drawn, your schematic looks correct. Are you sure your PCB footprint matches the part's pin numbering? Have you tried replacing it with a new on in case the one you're currently trying to use it dead?

yes , they match and I tried building 2 copies , both of them don't work

How much current does your motor need?

@jamesmcgrath - Thanks for adding that part of the schematic. Please also update the question with the troubleshooting so far - here are just a few examples of info which would help: Which supplier did the MOSFETs come from? Have you confirmed they are working normally elsewhere e.g. by soldering one to any available prototyping board to switch a simple LED+resistor load? Or did you use any other test method (e.g. checking for SD short)? Also, can you add a photo of that area of your PCB in case readers spot any concerns? Can you add PCB layout from that area (to doublecheck footprint etc.)?

what GPIO# are you using?
